# How to get the inner div of the nested div structure into the new line using flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, nested, newline

[image]

I want the inner div (Mem 3) in the new line, just below Mem 1, and I do not want to change the div structure at any cost. Please help.

Like this => [image]

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-child {
  border: solid blue;
}

.flex-fgc {
  border: solid blue;
}

.flex-inner-gc {
  border: solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div class='flex-child'>
    Mem 1
  </div>
  <div class='flex-fgc'>
    <div>
      Mem 2
    </div>
    <div class='flex-inner-gc'>
      Mem 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried 'flex: 1 1 100;' for the flex-inner-gc.

Comment: "Dissolve" `.flex-fgc` via `display: contents`, and make `.flex-inner-gc` take full width, using `flex: 0 0 100%` ... and then maybe limit the width of the outer container, or make that `inline-flex`, depending on how exactly you need it to behave.

Comment: *Flexbox layout* goes only **one level deep**, therefore any flexbox rule defined for `.flex-inner-gc` (and/or the unclassed `div`) has no effect.

Comment: @CBroe - Your suggestion actually works, but I am not sure if display: contents is a good practice. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

float can easily do this.

```css
.flex-child {
  border: solid blue;
  float: left;
}

.flex-fgc > * {
  float: left;
  border: solid blue;
}

.flex-inner-gc {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class='flex-container'>
  <div class='flex-child'>
    Mem 1
  </div>
  <div class='flex-fgc'>
    <div>
      Mem 2
    </div>
    <div class='flex-inner-gc'>
      Mem 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to use flex. It is possible to get this result using flex?